# MSVC error with constexpr array as template non-type parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, constexpr

I'm trying to understand if what I'm seeing is an MSVC compiler bug or a misunderstanding on my part. I'm trying to use a simple compile-time string literal template parameter, like so:

```c++
constexpr const char teststr[] = "teststr";

template <const char *N>
struct Test {
  static constexpr const char *name = N;
};

using TEST = Test<teststr>;
```

However, MSVC reports that the `teststr` parameter is not a compile-time expression: `error C2975: 'Test': invalid template argument for 'N', expected compile-time constant expression` (on the `using TEST` line).

Is this my mistake, or a compiler bug? I am using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [compiler bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/155480/vc-cannot-use-a-const-char-as-non-type-template-ar.html).

In addition, it is a [C++11 feature](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1155) to permit addresses of objects with internal linkage in template arguments, not C++14.

Answer (score 0):

Is it important that name is static ?

This compiles with MSVC 2015:

```
char teststr[] = "teststr";

template <const char *N>
struct Test
{
    const char *name = N;
};

using TEST = Test<teststr>;
```